# Reduce Firebase storage bandwith

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm developing a video streaming app at the moment and I noticed really high bandwidth in my app, actually. I'm using the free **[spark plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)** and I'm reaching the limit of the free plan with **5** videos already.

I'm streaming the videos within my app and they aren't bigger than 10mb and uploaded in my firebase storage. I'm saving the firebase storage link in my realtime database to make it playable in the app.

I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong, with 5 videos less than 10mb and I'm consuming 300mb bandwith in ~1 hour. For every video which is being played it's taking around 20-30mb bandwidth.

How can I improve that? When I have 1000 users, I will pay thousands of dollars per month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just store unlisted youtube videos and use that in your app instead. Video streaming is a costly thing in general but this way you can do it for free.

You can simply store the link to the youtube videos in firebase and use them in your app.

Comment: That's a really good cost-efficient advice. Have you tried this before? Is there any terms & conditions clause that would prevent this from being a mid-term solution?

Comment: @Michal Watch google itself if you don't believe me: https://youtu.be/N2OG1w6bGFo?t=2069

Comment: This is pure gold. +1 for even finding an official talk! 

Comment: @HosseinYousefi this is great thank you! so I also have a section with audio files, how to handle that?

Comment: @HosseinYousefi I mean like is there a way to do this with audio too? with youtube or youtube music?

Comment: @MarcelDz You could probably use youtube there as well. Possibly with a single frame/only audio unlisted video.

Comment: Lmao this is actually genius